# Safe decoding in python ('?' symbol instead of exception)

Tags: python

I have code:

```
encoding = guess_encoding()    
text = unicode(text, encoding)
```

when wrong symbol appears in text UnicodeDecode exception is raised. How can I silently skip exception replacing wrong symbol with '?' ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
text = unicode(text, encoding, "replace")
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode):

> 'replace' causes the official Unicode replacement character, U+FFFD, to be used to replace input characters which cannot be decoded.

If you want to use `"?"` instead of the official Unicode replacement character, you can do

```
text = text.replace(u"\uFFFD", "?")
```

after converting to unicode.

Comment: Add `u` before the string `u"\ufffd"` in Python 2.x otherwise the `replace()` function doesn't work. btw, `u'\ufffd'` is already a question mark (inside a diamond): `�`

Comment: an update this works now ```text = unicode(f.read(), errors = "replace")```

Comment: @harrypotter0 If you want to have this functionality for files in Python 3, your are better off using `open(filename, errors="replace")`, which wil perform the conversion directly while reading from the file.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, you can decode a `bytes` object into a string using the `decode` method. It accepts two parameters:

- `encoding`, which is `"utf-8"` by default, and
- `errors`, which defines what to do on illegal character sequences. The default value is `"strict"`, which raises a `UnicodeDecodeError`; other alternatives are `ignore` and `replace` -- the latter replaces illegal characters with the Unicode replacement character `"\uFFFD"`.

Therefore, you'd need to do this to decode-and-replace:

```py
encoding = guess_encoding()
text = text_bytes.decode(encoding, errors='replace').replace('\uFFFD', '?')
```

As [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224089/safe-decoding-in-python-symbol-instead-of-exception#comment89472328_5224130) pointed out in a comment, you can supply the `errors` argument directly to `open`; otherwise you'd get the decode errors while reading the file (if it falls out of the character map).